# Error de sintaxis en eventos de Javascript

Tags: javascript, eventos, dom

Es un programa que dependiendo de si el btn pierde o gana "el foco", este cambia su fondo. Estoy intentando buscar algún error dentro del código pero creo que todo está correcto. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar o decir que tengo mal dentro de la sintaxis?

```js
// Create btn 
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  var btnText = document.createTextNode('Click Me2!');
  btn.append(btnText);
  document.body.appendChild(btn);


  // Events
  btn.setAttribute('id', 'BTN');
  document.getElementById('BTN').addEventListener("onfocus", focus1);
  document.getElementById('BTN').addEventListener("onblur", blur1);


  function focus1(){
   document.getElementById('BTN').style.backgroundColor = 'red';

  }

  function blur1(){
   document.getElementById('BTN').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hazlo de esta manera, así puedes agregarle los eventos, si ya tienes el elemento boton y te evitas buscarlo al momento de crearlo :D . En JS los HTMLElements poseen algunos metodos o eventos con el prefix `on` como son el `onfocus`, `onblur`, `onclick` , etc.

```js
// Create btn 
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  var btnText = document.createTextNode('Click Me2!');
  btn.append(btnText);


  // Events
  btn.setAttribute('id', 'BTN');
  btn.onfocus = focus1;
  btn.onblur = blur1;


  function focus1(){
   document.getElementById('BTN').style.backgroundColor = 'red';

  }

  function blur1(){
   document.getElementById('BTN').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

  }

  document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para agregar un listener debes quitar el string 'on'

Pero para buttons me parece debes usar `onmouseover` y `onmouseleave`

```
let btn = document.getElementById('BTN');
btn.addEventListener("mouseover", focus1);
btn.addEventListener("mouseleave", blur1);

function focus1() {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}

function blur1() {
    btn..style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}
```